# Angular app hash-routing not working as expected

Tags: angular, nginx

I am running my Angualar7 app in docker container. It was working fine in localhost, but when I run it in docker. It can able to reach abc.xyz, from there I can goto abc.xyz/dashboard, abc.xyz/browseIdea from clicks on homepage. But, when I am hitting directly hitting the url like abc.xyz/dashboard, it is showing 404 not found.

1.Do, I need to change nginx configuration?

To fix the problem, I added hash routing

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash : true})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

So, it fixes the problem of **404 not found**, But, it is on refresh in abc.xyz/#/dashboard url redirecting to abc.xyz/#. As, to server url after hash will not be sent. Then, can not we use hashrouting for only component routing?

And, If I remove hashrouting in localhost on refreshing it is staying in the same url where I refreshed

2. Why hash routing is redirecting to path ''. I saw one application 4-5 months ago using hashrouting and that was not redirecting to path '' i.e, abc.xyz/#

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use hash routing strategy, then you should configure your server and direct the requests to the index.html of your application. add the below code in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: I don't know how to add .htaccess file to nginx config file. I read in some place it was written  you can not import, you just need to convert into corresponding nginx config, for which I used this link http://winginx.com/en/htaccess and put your htaccess code, which added one line in location/{} i.e, <rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html;>. And after adding when I opened localhost it gave "505 internal server error" and in error.log "1 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/index.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost""